# Class PHPMailer not found in

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Necesito ayuda, necesito que se manden correos y al momento de registrar un ticket debe de mandar uno pero solo se guarda en la BD y no manda correo y manda este error "class phpmailer not found in (directorio donde esta el archivo)".

[image: codigo]

Comment: Ya revisaste bien la ruta donde tienes el archivo y la instancia de la clase?

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código donde importar la clase.

Comment: listo ya esta la imagen

Comment: Si el orden es el de la imagen, prueba primero importar las clases y luego instancia las mismas.

Comment: lo de arriba quiere decir que muevas el public function para abajo y los require para arriba fuera de public function

Comment: creo que primero deberias establecer los "require" y luego hacer uso de la clase

Answer (score 1):

Segun la documentación:

```
<?php
 // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
 // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

 //Load composer's autoloader
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

 $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer